# System heating up since recent installations

Tags: arch-linux, temperature

Recently, after some operations on my machine, its temperature began to raise. Let's begin with some information.

#### Machine caracteristics

- Sony VAIO SVE1511C5E laptop
- Intel Core i7
- 8Go RAM
- AMD Radeon graphics
- 500Gb hard drive

#### Current system caracteristics

- Latest Arch Linux (3.10.10-1-ARCH)
- Working with Intel Integrated Graphics (supposedly, I'm not sure I did this configuration correctly).

#### What I did until now...

A few days ago, I decided it was be time to abandon the classic "Ubuntu/Windows 7" dual-boot, and switched to Arch Linux, which I've used for quite a long time on other machines.

- I started by shreding the hard drive, to make it "clean". One pass random, one pass with zeros (from sector 2048 to the end).
- I installed Arch Linux, everything went fine.

But the problem occured after this. Back when I was under the Ubuntu/Windows 7 dual-boot, my computer's temperatures were reasonnable. I had sent the machine to Sony for repairs once (the fan was apparently broken), and since then, everything ran around 40/50°C (idle), and rarely reached 60/65°C during big tasks.

Now that W7/Ubuntu disappeared, these temperatures are nothing but old memories.

- When doing nothing (idle), the machine stays around 60°C.
- When working harder, it reaches 75°C/80°C very quickly.
- I did not try the heaviest tasks such as running IDE's, compiling big programs, and so on.

Right now, as I'm asking this question, `sensors` outputs :

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +61.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +58.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +57.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter

temp1:        +52.5°C
```

In order to "fix" this problem, I tried/did the following :

- I installed and configured `laptop-mode-tools` as suggested by the Arch community.
- I installed `cpupower` and set it to work under the `powersave` governor (CPU Frequency Scaling).
- I checked my BIOS for fan-related parameters, but there's none I can see.
- I *tried* to work with Intel's graphics instead of using my AMD card, but I'm not even sure this worked (any way I could check it?)
- I *tried* to use `fancontrol` and `pwmconfig` but apparently, there's not pwm-capable modules loaded. I couldn't succesfully load `it87`.
- I've set the ATI power profile to `low`.
- I've set the ATI power method to `profile`.

After that, I decided to try other distributions, in case there would be a problem specific to Arch.

- OpenSUSE shows the same behaviour.
- Back to Ubuntu, same, even if I used it when dual-booting with W7 !

Having tried most of the things I know when it comes to high temperatures, I have to admit I've now run out of ideas... Is there anything I've missed, something I should try on my machine ? Something I've lost when I shreded my hard drive ?

### PowerTop results

#### Overview

Summary: 290.5 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 6.8% CPU use

```
            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
         23.6 ms/s      50.7        Process        /usr/lib32/skype/skype
          6.8 ms/s      51.2        Process        /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
        413.2 µs/s      25.3        Process        [rcu_preempt]
          7.6 ms/s      21.2        Process        /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --typ
          0.9 ms/s      17.5        Timer          tick_sched_timer
          7.0 ms/s      14.9        Process        /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp :0 -aut
        432.5 µs/s      15.2        Process        tint2
        687.9 µs/s      15.4        Process        urxvt
          1.8 ms/s      15.2        Interrupt      [6] tasklet(softirq)
          4.3 ms/s       9.9        kWork          ath_hw_pll_work
        323.9 µs/s       9.7        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
        321.6 µs/s       8.0        Process        /usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/
          1.0 ms/s       6.8        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
          3.1 µs/s       3.8        kWork          ieee80211_dynamic_ps_enable_wor
          1.2 ms/s       2.1        Process        sensors
          1.5 ms/s       1.9        Process        watch
```

#### Idle stats

```
            Package |             Core    |            CPU 0       CPU 1
                    |                     | Actual    1.6 GHz     1.7 GHz
Idle        96.8%   | Idle        99.6%   | Idle        99.6%      100.0%
2.40 GHz     2.7%   | 2.60 GHz     0.0%   | 2.60 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
2.60 GHz     0.0%   | 2.50 GHz     0.0%   | 2.50 GHz     0.0%
2.50 GHz     0.0%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%   | 1.60 GHz     0.1%
1.60 GHz     0.1%   | 1.60 GHz     0.1%   | 2.21 GHz     0.0%
2.21 GHz     0.1%   | 2.21 GHz     0.0%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%
2.31 GHz     0.0%   | 2.31 GHz     0.0%   | 2.31 GHz     0.0%
1500 MHz     0.0%   | 1500 MHz     0.0%   | 1500 MHz     0.0%
1300 MHz     0.0%   | 1.80 GHz     0.3%   | 1.80 GHz     0.3%
1400 MHz     0.0%   |                     |

                    |             Core    |            CPU 2       CPU 3
                    |                     | Actual    1.8 GHz     1.7 GHz
                    | Idle        99.9%   | Idle       100.0%      100.0%
                    | 2.60 GHz     0.0%   | 2.60 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.40 GHz     0.0%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.31 GHz     0.0%   | 1.60 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1500 MHz     0.0%   | 1.80 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1300 MHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 1400 MHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 1.60 GHz     0.0%   |
                    | 1.80 GHz     0.0%   |
                    |                     |

                    |             Core    |            CPU 4       CPU 5
                    |                     | Actual    1.9 GHz     2.2 GHz
                    | Idle        99.9%   | Idle        99.9%      100.0%
                    | 2.21 GHz     0.1%   | 2.21 GHz     0.1%        0.0%
                    | 2.40 GHz     0.0%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%
                    | 2.10 GHz     0.0%   | 2.10 GHz     0.0%
                    | 1.80 GHz     0.0%   | 1.80 GHz     0.0%
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |

                    |             Core    |            CPU 6       CPU 7
                    |                     | Actual    2.3 GHz     2.0 GHz
                    | Idle        97.3%   | Idle        97.3%      100.0%
                    | 2.40 GHz     2.7%   | 2.40 GHz     2.7%        0.0%
                    | 2.60 GHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 1.60 GHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 2.31 GHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 1300 MHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                    | 1500 MHz     0.0%   |                          0.0%
                | 1.71 GHz     0.4%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.40 GHz     0.0%   | 2.60 GHz     0.1%        0.1%
                    | 2.60 GHz     0.1%   | 3.10 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.71 GHz     0.0%   | 2.81 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.81 GHz     0.0%   | 1400 MHz     0.0%
                    | 1400 MHz     0.1%   | 1300 MHz     0.0%
                    | 1300 MHz     0.0%   | 2.10 GHz     0.1%
                    | 2.10 GHz     0.1%   |
                    |                     |

                    |             Core    |            CPU 4       CPU 5
                    |                     | Actual    1.8 GHz     1.8 GHz
                    | Idle        97.8%   | Idle        98.5%       99.3%
                    | 3.10 GHz     0.0%   | 3.10 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 3.00 GHz     0.0%   | 3.00 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.21 GHz     0.0%   | 2.21 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.31 GHz     0.0%   | 2.31 GHz     0.0%        0.3%
                    | 1.60 GHz     0.1%   | 1.60 GHz     0.1%        0.0%
                    | 1.91 GHz     0.4%   | 2.00 GHz     0.2%        0.0%
                    | 2.00 GHz     0.2%   | 1300 MHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1300 MHz     0.0%   | 1400 MHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1400 MHz     0.0%   | 2.90 GHz     0.0%        0.2%
                    | 2.90 GHz     0.0%   | 2.10 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.10 GHz     0.1%   | 2.60 GHz     0.0%        0.1%
                    | 2.60 GHz     0.0%   | 1.71 GHz     0.3%        0.1%
                    | 1.71 GHz     0.5%   | 1.80 GHz     0.7%        0.0%
                    | 1.80 GHz     0.8%   | 1.91 GHz     0.1%        0.0%
                    | 1500 MHz     0.1%   | 2.40 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.40 GHz     0.0%   | 2.50 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.50 GHz     0.0%   | 2.71 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.71 GHz     0.0%   | 2.81 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.81 GHz     0.0%   | 1500 MHz     0.0%
                    | 1200 MHz     0.0%   |

                    |             Core    |            CPU 6       CPU 7
                    |                     | Actual    1.8 GHz     1.8 GHz
                    | Idle        99.0%   | Idle        99.1%       99.8%
                    | 3.10 GHz     0.0%   | 3.10 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.21 GHz     0.0%   | 2.00 GHz     0.1%        0.0%
                    | 2.31 GHz     0.0%   | 2.90 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.00 GHz     0.1%   | 2.10 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1.91 GHz     0.1%   | 2.60 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 1.60 GHz     0.1%   | 2.50 GHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.90 GHz     0.0%   | 1.60 GHz     0.1%        0.0%
                    | 2.10 GHz     0.0%   | 1.71 GHz     0.1%        0.1%
                    | 2.60 GHz     0.0%   | 1400 MHz     0.0%        0.0%
                    | 2.50 GHz     0.0%   | 1500 MHz     0.1%        0.0%
```

#### Frequency stats

```
          Package   |             Core    |            CPU 0       CPU 1
                    |                     | C0 active   0.4%        0.0%
                    |                     | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     | C1E-IVB     0.0%    0.0 ms  2.6%    6.6 ms
C2 (pc2)    0.9%    |                     |
C3 (pc3)    0.1%    | C3 (cc3)    0.0%    | C3-IVB      0.1%    0.1 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
C6 (pc6)    1.0%    | C6 (cc6)    0.0%    | C6-IVB      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
C7 (pc7)   91.5%    | C7 (cc7)   96.9%    | C7-IVB     98.7%   39.9 ms 97.4%  246.1 ms

                    |             Core    |            CPU 2       CPU 3
                    |                     | C0 active   0.1%        0.1%
                    |                     | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     | C1E-IVB     0.1%    0.3 ms  0.9%    1.8 ms
                    |                     |
                    | C3 (cc3)    1.6%    | C3-IVB      1.6%    2.7 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C6 (cc6)    0.0%    | C6-IVB      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C7 (cc7)   97.4%    | C7-IVB     97.4%   49.2 ms 99.1%   91.0 ms

                    |             Core    |            CPU 4       CPU 5
                    |                     | C0 active   0.1%        0.0%
                    |                     | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     | C1E-IVB     0.1%    0.5 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     |
                    | C3 (cc3)    0.0%    | C3-IVB      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C6 (cc6)    0.0%    | C6-IVB      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C7 (cc7)   99.5%    | C7-IVB     99.4%   71.8 ms100.1%  144.5 ms

                    |             Core    |            CPU 6       CPU 7
                    |                     | C0 active   3.1%        0.1%
                    |                     | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     | C1E-IVB     0.2%    0.2 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     |
                    | C3 (cc3)    0.1%    | C3-IVB      0.1%    0.2 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C6 (cc6)    0.0%    | C6-IVB      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C7 (cc7)   96.7%    | C7-IVB     96.8%   22.2 ms 99.9%  144.2 ms
```

#### Device stats

```
Usage     Device name
6.9%        CPU misc
6.9%        CPU core
100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
100.0%        Display backlight
99.6%        Display backlight
0.0 ops/s   GPU core
0.0 ops/s   GPU misc
100.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
100.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
100.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
100.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
100.0%        Radio device: btusb
100.0%        Radio device: ath9k
100.0%        Radio device: Sony Notebook Control Driver
100.0%        Radio device: Sony Notebook Control Driver
100.0%        USB device: USB2.0 Camera (LOEA11P2BF13827W01781)
100.0%        USB device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller (Atheros Communicat
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
```

(most tunable items are set to Good, except USB suspension. Changes don't go further than +/- 2°C)

Comment: Were you using the proprietary ATI drivers before?  They may be better with power management than the open source ones.  You might also try running `powertop`.

Comment: I cannot install the `catalyst` package, because there's no more support for it since Xorg 1.14 (I tried to use my Intel Integrated Graphics, and `xf86-video-ati`, without results). I added the `powertop` diagnosis to my question, I'm afraid I can't get anything from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some researches, deep in the AUR, in the world of crazy Arch developers, I found an very probable answer to the question.

As excepted, the problem comes from the use of the Open Source driver, which power management (and therefore, CPU usage/temperature) is horrible. For these reasons, and under those circumstances of mine, `xf86-video-ati` and friends should **never** be used. However, the *big* issue is that the `catalyst` package is no longer supported with Xorg 1.14. Usually, you would have to downgrade Xorg, and stop it from upgrading. I did differently.

There is the procedure I followed :

- I downloaded `yaourt` and its AUR dependency `package-query` (which requires `yajl` from the *official repositories*), and stored the tarballs in my home directory for further use.
- I reinstalled Arch Linux from scratch, because using `xf86-video-ati` brought a lot of dependencies to most of my applications, especially Skype and Chromium. I think that's the best thing to do to keep it clean. I kept `/home` away from the `pacstrap` installation, and re-mounted it before generating the `fstab` file.
- Once the system was ready (`base-devel` installed, configurations done), I installed `package-query` and `yaourt`, in order to download `catalyst-test`, the wonderful package made by our Archers. There may have been some dependencies there, I don't remember everything. **Important notice : installing this package will require the re-compilation of linux kernel headers. Even if `yaourt` takes care of that, the computer heated up pretty high during the package compression.**
- With `catalyst-test` installed, I followed the basic instructions for the ATI Catalyst driver (Arch Wiki) : generate the configuration with `aticonfig --install`, blacklist the `radeon` driver, make sure the `fglrx` module is loaded on boot (`/etc/modules.load/catalyst`), disable KMS (`nomodeset` in the kernel parameters), regenerate the GRUB configuration with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, reboot. At boot, make sure the `fglrx` module is loaded (`lsmod | fglrx`), and that the direct rendering is activated (`fglrxinfo`).
- I reinstalled my packages. Most of my configurations where untouched because I kept my `/home` directory away from the `pacstrap` process on reinstall.

With this driver, I've noticed a significant lowering of my temperatures, even if I still have some configurations to do (laptop-related issues) :

- Resetting `cpupower`.
- Resetting `laptop-mode-tools`.
- Apply `powertop` tunable items configuration.

A huge round of applause to the Arch Community, and thank you.

Comment: Even though I found some satisfaction in this installation, there's still a long way to go. Hoping further improvements are to be implemented in next versions.